# 1С 8.3.10 + Google Maps JavaScript API

Tags: 1с

Подскажите, если кто сталкивался с подобной проблемой.
на 1С 8.3 реализован механизм определения координат и установка широты и долготы.

недавно в обработке 1С при формировании карты стало выводить сообщение "Ваш браузер не поддерживается Google Maps JavaScript API. Выберите другой."

До этого я использовал тег `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9">`
всё работало.

Прочитал про поддержку браузеров в google https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/browsersupport?hl=ru

Переписал тег `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=11">`

Результат: не работает.

Подскажите куда копать, как быть.

[image: Скрин]

Comment: Какая версия ОС?

Comment: Пишу на Windows 10, клиенты работают на тонком клиенте через http, их операционная система начиная от 7 и до 10

Comment: Сталкнулся сейчас с такой же проблемой (может она появилась раньше но сообщили мне только сейчас). Сделал всё как выше описано, но карта не открывается, просто белый экран и при этом никаких ошибок не выдает. Проверял на виндовс 10х64 и виндовс 7х32. Проверил как на тонком, так и на толстом клиенте, записи вносил для "1Cv8c.exe" и "1Cv8.exe". Куда ещё можно покапать ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1С использует стандартный com компонент webbrowser который предоставляет windows. По умолчанию для всех приложений эта компонента работает в режиме совместимости IE7. Для смены режима совместимости требуется добавить в реестр ключ с именем приложения и кодом уровня совместимости.

Подробнее здесь:
https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2011/May/21/Web-Browser-Control-Specifying-the-IE-Version

Comment: т.е. я так понимаю что тег в теле html `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10" />` (формируемый на стороне 1С) Использовать смысла нет и выход только править реестр?

Comment: `<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" /> <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=11">`, я так и не смог найти иной подход. Сам работаю на Win10 + 8.3.11, такого не наблюдаю. А так совету просто сделать дампы реестра. Если надо могу скинуть на почту. Отпиши ящик.

Answer (score 1):

В общем получилось.
изучил ссылку, сделал, всё заработало.
для тех кто будет делать подобные вещи, очень важно создавать ключи для 32bit 64bit

ни у тег `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=11">`

> Aleksandr K. Большое спасибо!

Comment: Александр, был рад помочь. Я бы хотел дополнить ответ. Напишите, пожалуйста, какие ключи в какие ветки Вы добавили - я укажу это в ответе перед ссылкой.

Answer (score 0):

**Операционной система 64bit**

Ветка реестра:

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Internet
>   Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION

Для клиенте 1С 32bit

Добавляем ключ (DWORD): `1Cv8c.exe` с параметром - HEX: 2AF8 или десятичное значение: 11000

Для клиенте 1С 64bit

Добавляем ключ (QWORD): `1Cv8c.exe` с параметром - HEX: 2AF8 или десятичное значение: 11000

**Операционной система 32bit**

Ветка реестра:

> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet
>   Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION

Для клиенте 1С 32bit

Добавляем ключ (DWORD): `1Cv8c.exe` с параметром - HEX: 2AF8 или десятичное значение: 11000

Answer (score 0):

Хотел автоматизировать данный процесс, не прибегая к ручному внесения ключей в реестр, но не получилось.
Сделал просто дамп этих веток.

Но если интересно можно доделать мои наброски.

Код 1С:

Чтение проходит нормально.

```
&НаКлиенте
Процедура ПрочитатьЗначение(Команда)

    // Для указания нужного раздела реестра во всех методах этого класса используется некоторое числовое значение, соответствующее определенному разделу.
    // Название раздела             Шестнадцатеричное значение      Десятичное значение
    // HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT            0x80000000                      2147483648
    // HKEY_CURRENT_USER            0x80000001                      2147483649
    // HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE           0x80000002                      2147483650
    // HKEY_USERS                   0x80000003                      2147483651
    // HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG          0x80000005                      2147483653
    // HKEY_DYN_DATA (Windows 9x)   0x80000006                      2147483655
    //
    // Методы
    // http://www.script-coding.com/WMI_StdRegProv.html
    //


    Перем Значение; // В эту переменную запишем значение из реестра

    Реестр = ПолучитьCOMОбъект("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\default:StdRegProv");

    Реестр.CreateKey("2147483650", "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION");

    // Читаем значение ключа 1cv8c.exe из ветки 
    // HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION в переменную Значение
    Реестр.GetDWORDValue("2147483650", "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION", "1cv8c.exe", Значение);

    Сообщить(Значение);

КонецПроцедуры
```

Но вот запись не происходит. Особо не заморачивался, если будут подсказки по записи, то выложу обработку с примером.

т.е. ошибок нет, но ключа после записи не появляется.

Запись.

```
&НаКлиенте
Процедура УстановитьЗначение(Команда)

    Реестр = ПолучитьCOMОбъект("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\default:StdRegProv");

    Реестр.CreateKey("2147483650", "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION\1cv8c.exe");

    // Записываем значение ключа 1cv8c.exe в ветку
    // HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION
    Реестр.SetDWORDValue("2147483650", "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION", "1cv8c.exe", 11000);

КонецПроцедуры
```